# How to Block All App Notifications but Allow Phone Calls?

Tags: notifications, customization

I have been looking in several Android forums today trying to figure out if there is a way to block all app notifications with a single action or setting but allow phone calls? I'm trying to make it where I'm not distracted during the day by all the app notifications but if family members need to call me they still can. In essence, it would be something like airplane mode except I can still receive calls. Once the setting is removed, all blocked notifications would then show up like the functionality with airplane mode so none are missed.

Does anyone know of a setting on Android for that or an app on the Google Play Store? I know about Do Not Disturb but that only seems to silence the notifications, not actually block them from showing up.

Comment: Your Android version and device? Is the Android rooted?

Comment: Android version is 5.0 Lollipop and my device is a Verizon Samsung Galaxy S5. It is NOT rooted. I have looked into rooting it but haven't found a successful way of rooting the Verizon S5 last I looked.

Comment: [Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff) can easily do it. It requires root access however.

Answer (score 0):

### With root access

I used the application [Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff) (you need root access). It is straightforward and simple. You simply uncheck all apps by one click and then tick only calls.

### With no root access

Go to:

Settings-> Application Manager-> (select app) -> Disable all notifications (this varies according to your Android version)

I'm a afraid you have to do it for every app.